# Not sure how to execute complex Query with Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm stuck on a query I'm trying to execute. I have attached an image of the datamodel below. Essentally, I got 6 tables with various relations. Here's a quick summary:

1. One `User` can have many `Projects`, and each `Expense` is tied to a specific project
2. Each project can have many users, and each user can have many projects, put together through a joined table - `UserProject`
3. To indicate the level of access a user has to a specific project, a field called *role* is added to the `UserProject` table - a user can either be a member or an admin of a project

The query I wish to construct is to fetch all expenses that are created by the logged in user (`request.user`) and all expenses of **all**  projects where the user has the role of **admin** from the `UserProject` table.

See image of data model below:

[image: Data model]

Any idea how I would proceed with that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out by using Q queries

```
specific_project_users = Expense.objects.filter(
    Q(project__projectuser__user=self.user),
    Q(project__projectuser__role='admin') | Q(user=self.user)
).values("user__id")
users = User.objects.filter(id__in=specific_project_users)
```

Not sure how efficient the query is though.

The raw SQL query translates to this

```
SELECT ... 
FROM "accounts_user" 
WHERE "accounts_user"."id" 
IN (SELECT U0."user_id" 
FROM "finances_expense" U0 
INNER JOIN "project" U1 
ON (U0."project_id" = U1."id") 
INNER JOIN "projectuser" U2 ON (U1."id" = U2."project_id") 
WHERE (U2."user_id" = 1 AND (U2."role" = admin OR U0."user_id" = 1)))
```